# ¿Cómo hacer esta consulta de fechas en hanna?

Tags: sql, hana

Agradecería me puedan apoyar con esta interrogante que tengo.

my query, esta hecho en hana de sap pero básicamente cumple lo mismo que SQL, Necesito añadir un campo llamado (presupuesto) de otra tabla **@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1** (donde tengo los meses distribuidos por columnas)

```
SELECT T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2" as "Cuenta", 
T1."AcctName",
T1."AccntntCod",
sum(T0."Debit"-T0."Credit") as "Saldo_SOL",
sum(T0."SYSDeb"-T0."SYSCred") as "Saldo_ME"

FROM JDT1 T0  
INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0."Account" = T1."AcctCode"
INNER JOIN "@EXC_RUBROS" T2 ON T1."U_EXC_OPEREXPEN" = T2."U_EXC_CODRUB"
LEFT JOIN "@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1" T3 ON  T3."U_EXC_CTACONT" = T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2"


WHERE T0."RefDate" BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20200331'

group by T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2", T1."AcctName",T1."AccntntCod"
order by T1."Segment_0"||'-'||T1."Segment_1"||'-'||T1."Segment_2"
```

Este es parte de el Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debo añadir es la siguiente tabla **@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1** donde las columnas representan meses, y tengo que acumularlos en un campo llamado presupuesto segun el rango de fecha, esta tabla se relaciona con el query anterior, con las columnas (U_EXC_CTACON = Cuenta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es una parte de reporte final y la data acumulada de los meses tiene que ir Acumulado en Prespto M.E

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería su apoyo, lo hice de esta forma con case when pero solo me obtiene los datos de un solo mes

```
CASE 
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 1 THEN   T6."U_EXC_ENERO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 2 THEN   T6."U_EXC_FEBRERO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 3 THEN   T6."U_EXC_MARZO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 4 THEN   T6."U_EXC_ABRIL"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 5 THEN   T6."U_EXC_MAYO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 6 THEN   T6."U_EXC_JUNIO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 7 THEN   T6."U_EXC_JULIO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 8 THEN   T6."U_EXC_AGOSTO"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 9 THEN   T6."U_EXC_SETIEMBRE"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 10 THEN T6."U_EXC_OCTUBRE"
WHEN MONTH(:FInicio) = 11 THEN  T6."U_EXC_NOVIEMBRE"
ELSE T6."U_EXC_DICIEMBRE"   
END as presupuesto
```

Gracias de Antemano.

Comment: Eso no es código de SQL Server.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @EXC_PRESUPUESTO1, Esa tabla ya la tienes relacionada en tu consulta y de donde sacas esta :FInicio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es preparar primero un *CTE* o tabla derivada que resuma el presupuesto, simplemente haciendo una suma de los valores de enero a diciembre que haya que incluir en el resultado. Luego utilizas ese CTE o tabla derivada para incluir dicho valor en tu consulta principal.

Estoy asumiendo que tienes dos parámetros con las fechas de inicio y fin para las que te interesa obtener el valor y el CTE incluiría el presupuesto del mes, aunque la fecha de inicio sea mayor al primer día o la fecha final sea menor al último día del mes.

Es decir, Si la fecha de inicio es `'31/enero'`, el presupuesto de enero se incluye, igual si la fecha final es `'3/marzo'`, el presupuesto de marzo se incluye.

No es que no sea posible excluirlos, pero mi ejemplo funciona así.

Una precondición que **debe cumplirse** es que la fecha de inicio y final debieran pertenecer al mismo año calendario, y la fecha inicial ser menor a la final. Si no lo son, los resultados no son confiables.

Finalmente, en el ejemplo incluyo la lógica para sumar de enero a abril, ya con eso tienes la idea para realizar tu la consulta completa.

La consulta que te resume el valor del presupuesto es:

```
select   "U_EXC_CTACONT"
       , case when 1 between month(:FInicio) and month(:FFin) then "U_EXC_ENERO" else 0 end 
       + case when 2 between month(:FInicio) and month(:FFin) then "U_EXC_FEBRERO" else 0 end 
       + case when 3 between month(:FInicio) and month(:FFin) then "U_EXC_MARZO" else 0 end
       + case when 4 between month(:FInicio) and month(:FFin) then "U_EXC_ABRIL" else 0 end
         as PresupuestoFechas
  from "@EXC_PRESUPUESTO1"
 group by "U_EXC_CTACONT"
```

La idea es que con cada `case` decido si incluir el mes o no, según el mes de la fecha inicio y fecha final de los parámetros. En caso que el mes no sea incluido, devuelvo un `0` para que la suma pueda realizarse sin `null`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Si interpreto bien tu pregunta, basado en el Case que pones de ejemplo y a que indicas que "obtiene los datos de un solo mes", asumo que quieres incluir todas las columnas a partir del mes en cuestión.

Podrías lograrlo sumando el resultado de los distintos case:

```
CASE MONTH(:FInicio) = 1  THEN  T6."U_EXC_ENERO" ELSE 0 END + 
CASE MONTH(:FInicio) <= 2  THEN  T6."U_EXC_FEBRERO" ELSE 0 END +
CASE MONTH(:FInicio) <= 3  THEN  T6."U_EXC_MARZO" ELSE 0 END + 
...etc...
CASE MONTH(:FInicio) <= 11  THEN  T6."U_EXC_NOVIEMBRE" ELSE 0 END +
CASE MONTH(:FInicio) <= 12  THEN  T6."U_EXC_DICIEMBRE" ELSE 0 END
AS presupuesto
```

O más resumido (si tú SQL lo soporta) :

```
IIF(MONTH(:FInicio) = 1,T6."U_EXC_ENERO",0) +
IIF(MONTH(:FInicio) <= 2,T6."U_EXC_FEBRERO",0) +
IIF(MONTH(:FInicio) <= 3,T6."U_EXC_MARZO",0) +
...etc...
AS presupuesto
```